# Discard scale transform of Camera in Viewport3D

Tags: c#, transformation, viewport3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a main `Viewport3D` with `mCamera`, that is controlled by `TrackballDecorator`. What I want is to create another `Viewport3D` with just a cube in it to represent current camera direction on the main viewport.

This code:

```
Matrix3D TransformationMatrix = mCamera.Transform.Value;
// ?
OrientationCamera.Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(TransformationMatrix);
```

works well, besides the fact that I don't want the `OrientationCamera` to apply the zoom as the main one (I want it just to rotate).

I can see that only values `M11`, `M22`, `M33` of the matrix are changing when operating on zoom with the main camera, but they also change when I'm rotating it, and any change I try to apply to those resulted my preview cube to transform in an unexpected way.

Does anyone have any idea how to discard the `ScaleTransform` from the transformation matrix? Or maybe there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three rows (or columns) in a pure rotation matrix are unit vectors. If you apply a scale, these vectors aren't of unit-length any more. You can apply an inverse scale to get rid of the scale. Assuming that the scale is equal in all three directions:

```
var m11 = TransformationMatrix.M11;
var m12 = TransformationMatrix.M12;
var m13 = TransformationMatrix.M13;
var length = Math.Sqrt(m11 * m11 + m12 * m12 + m13 * m13);
var factor = 1 / length;
TransformationMatrix.Scale(new Vector3D(factor, factor, factor));
```